# Sql using where condition with case and Like

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a multiple parameter say @route in report builder.I need @route to be able to pass blank (' ') and when that happens everything is displayed on the result, which would be my default for parameter @route. ( as accomplished by 
        where route LIKE '%' + (LTRIM(RTRIM(@route))) + '%')

Basically do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @finalTable ft 
WHERE CASE WHEN @route = '' THEN route LIKE '%' + (LTRIM(RTRIM(@route))) + '%'
           ELSE  route IN (@route)
      END
```

To make things more clear:

@route is a string and say has 200 different values. I basically want to set a default value of ' ' (blank or null) and allow say 10 distinct values for the user to select from.  So basically if the user does not select anything ( 'cuz the default is blank or could be null )then  he/she still gets the whole result set. So if i restrict the user to only pass single values and ' ' being one of them then where @route  LIKE '%' + (LTRIM(RTRIM(@route))) + '%' works but I would like it to be done with multiple values being passed as well. I hope it clarifies things more now!!

Any help is appreciated.. thank you in advance

Comment: My guess is your @route when not empty is something like `'1,5,10'` ??

Comment: @route is actually a varchar so something like 'Oral', 'Injection'....@juancarlosoropeza

Comment: Then you need explain better your question, because now i dont see the need for  `LIKE`

Comment: added some more clarification @juancarlosoropeza

Comment: So how looks the string with multiple parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal approach is someting like:

```
WHERE route = @route OR @route = ''
```

Often `NULL` is used for this purpose instead of an empty string:

```
WHERE route = @route OR @route IS NULL
```

Comment: the problem is route could have say 20 string values and the user could only select like 3 or 5 or 10 .... so when you use multiple or with like .... then how would you make sure to have covered it all?

Comment: @inquisitiveSQL . . . You can't use `IN` either, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to pass a list of parameters directly to an IN statement unfortunately.

If you want to do that, I'd suggest the easiest way is to send a table-valued parameter containing a list of your IDs. That way you can join against it to get the same effect as the IN query you've suggested.

This won't directly permit you to do your conditional WHERE clause, but what you can then do is check whether the table-valued parameter contains any rows at all and act accordingly - perhaps something like:

```
DECLARE @Routes IDList;

SELECT * 
FROM @finalTable ft 
        LEFT JOIN @Routes r
            ON ft.Route=r.Route
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Recs FROM @Routes) cnt
WHERE
    1= CASE WHERE cnt.Recs = 0 THEN 1 
        ELSE  CASE WHEN r.Route IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: this is intresting.. not sure if I could use it with report builder like i want to but i will play around with it. thx @eftpotrm

Answer (score 0):

if your @route is something like `'1,5,10'`

```
SELECT * 
FROM @finalTable ft 
WHERE ',' + @route + ',' LIKE  '%,' + ft.route + ',%'
```